# Samsung Tab - Internet(Default Browser): window.location file download not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, pdf-generation

I have a web application that makes a JS call to a backend service, which then calls my SSRS to generate a .PDF report in real time.

I have a simple JS function that uses window.location to call my C# method, which in turn will call the SSRS to generate my report.

```
 var url = '@Url.Action("GenerateMyReport", "Home")?reportId=' +report+'&downloadToken='+token;
 window.location = url;
```

This works across almost all major browsers. My reports download, and can be opened without issues.

The exception is the Samsung Tab default browser "Internet". I can see that the file downloads. However, when I swipe down to expose my recent downloads menu, I click on my downloaded file and get a "Could not open file message".

However, if I manually go to the Files>Download folder on the Tab, and open  the file, I have no issues.

Does anyone know what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: I would expect the string value for url to be formatted using double quotes and within the double quotes either pass a variable to the action as well as using single quotes and properly format your QueryString for the Url

Comment: I was setting my HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; but I had a spelling error in the word application.

Comment: how would we know that if you did not post all relevant code..? does that fix your issue..? if so please state that..